Incorrect content height for PdfDocument
I am creating a PDF from the contents of a scrollview. Each page, however, has a blank space at the bottom. I am calculating the height based on the newAttributes passed to the onLayout method of  PrintDocumentAdapter.
val pageSize = newAttributes.mediaSize?.heightMils
This is what I am using to set the height of bitmap but seems like bitmap is shorter than the actual page size and hence there is blank space at the bottom.
I checked the conversion of pixels to mils and vice-versa is applied where it should be. Since I am using the height from media attribute to print to the pdf page, I expected the entire page to have contents. What I might be missing here?
Code:
printManager.print(jobName, object : PrintDocumentAdapter() {
      override fun onLayout(oldAttributes: PrintAttributes?, newAttributes: PrintAttributes, cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal?, callback: LayoutResultCallback?, extras: Bundle?) {
        pdfDocument = PrintedPdfDocument(context, newAttributes)

        if (cancellationSignal?.isCanceled == true) {
          callback?.onLayoutCancelled()
          return
        }

        // This value is in mils, which is thousands of an inch
        pageSize = newAttributes.mediaSize?.heightMils!!

          // Convert to mils
        val contentSize = scrollView.getChildAt(0).height * 10
        

        numberOfPages = ceil(((contentSizeMils / pageSize).toDouble())).toInt()
        if (numberOfPages > 0) {
          PrintDocumentInfo.Builder(jobName)
            .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
            .setPageCount(numberOfPages)
            .build()
            .also { info ->
              callback?.onLayoutFinished(info, true)
            }
        } else {
          callback?.onLayoutFailed("Page count calculation failed.")
        }
      }

      override fun onWrite(pages: Array<PageRange>?, destination: ParcelFileDescriptor?, cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal?, callback: WriteResultCallback?) {
        for (i in 0 until numberOfPages) {

          // Convert to pixel
          val printableHeight = pageSize / 10

          val pageInfo = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(scrollView.getChildAt(0).width, printableHeight, i).create()
          val page = pdfDocument?.startPage(pageInfo)
          val canvas = page?.canvas

          // Calculate the portion of the content to be drawn for this page
          val start = i * printableHeight
          val end = ((i + 1) * printableHeight)

          // Create bitmap of the portion of the scroll view content for this page
          val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scrollView.getChildAt(0).width, end - start, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

          val contentCanvas = Canvas(bitmap)
          contentCanvas.translate(0f, (-start).toFloat()) // Translate canvas to the appropriate position
          scrollView.getChildAt(0).draw(contentCanvas)

          // Draw the bitmap onto the canvas
          canvas?.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null)

          pdfDocument?.finishPage(page)
        }

        try {
          pdfDocument?.writeTo(FileOutputStream(destination?.fileDescriptor))
        } catch (e: IOException) {
          callback?.onWriteFailed(e.toString())
          return
        } finally {
          pdfDocument?.close()
          pdfDocument = null
        }
        callback?.onWriteFinished(pages)

      }




Figured the reason:
While I was using the height received from PrintAtributes of onLayout(), the width I was using was that of the scrollview. The scrollview width was greater than that of the width in PrintAtributes and hence the content was being stretched to fit the given width. The stretching of width led to the blacnk space at the bottom of each pdf page.
Solution:
Scale the page before writing the bitmap to the canvas.
